# Meteor and Apache Wave

Tags: meteor, google-wave

I've been looking into Meteor and I'm really impressed so far.
I'm thinking that the diff/collaboration capabilities of Google (now Apache) Wave would dovetail nicely with Meteor, and have seen / played around with the node implementation of Wave.

I'm wondering if anyone has looked into porting that node implementation of Wave into Meteor.
Specifically, you'd need to use Redis, or change out Redis in the node-wave implementation with Mongo, and I'm questioning the best way to go about it...

Wondering what you think would be the best approach to doing so, and if you were to do it, where you'd begin (tweak the existing package, build a new one from scratch, etc)

thanks, and apologies if this is overly-vague.

Comment: slightly related: apparently one of the meteor core devs worked on wave - http://meteor.com/about/people

Comment: I missed that when I read their bios. Thanks! I have to say that meteor is already close to wave-like functionality - it's the handling of deltas / federated server config that's missing.

Comment: If you're looking for simultaneous editing, there's sharejs which uses node. That was written by an ex-google waver as well.